# Symfony 2 CSRF token issue

Tags: forms, symfony, csrf

I am having some problems with one of my online projects. I am getting this error:

> The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.

on every form and i can't log-out from session. The app was working fine a few days ago so it must be something wrong with the server. I can't figure out what.
 The CSRF tokens are generated fine, i checked.
 After i disabled the CSRF protection the form submitted but the flash message did not appear.
 Anyone had this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the token in the form?

```
{{ form_widget(form._token) }}
```

Or the less clean

```
{{ form_rest(form) }}
```

As for your other issue, you will have to be more specific.

Comment: Yes, the token is present in the form, i have checked that. As i said the app worked fine a few days ago. Something happened on the server, there is something wrong with the session, i guess. If i disable the CSRF the form works fine but the flash-bag message is not working. The log-out button is not working too. I have no idea where to look, i am not so good with servers.